# How can I halt juju and remove it from my local machine?

Tags: juju

I have juju running locally using LXC, and I'd like to completely remove it. Is removing the `juju` package enough, or do I need to go hunt down other things as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a running environment first you need to destroy it. If you have data you care about on those instances make sure to copy it someplace else! You can then destroy the environment:

```
juju destroy-environment
```

You then need to remove and purge lxc and it's associated dependencies (unless you plan on using LXC containers for something else.)

In your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` you probably specified a data dir, like so:

```
data-dir: /home/jorge/jujustuff
```

then you'll need to remove that as well, as well as `~/.juju/`.